# PAYPAL : going from sandbox to live REST-SDK-JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

***Hello ,Since everything is working perfect in sandbox mode im trying to switch to live mode .. i created a live app and got the live credentials but the issue is the backend still generating a sandbox.paypal.com link ... any solution ?***

```
    const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk");
const User = require("../../../Database/User");
const Order = require("../../../Database/Orders");
const { isUserAuthenticated } = require("../../Oauth/middlewares/auth");
const { Clean_input } = require("../../utils/utils");

paypal.configure({
  mode: "live", //sandbox or live
  client_id:
    "LIVE CLIENT ID",
  client_secret:
    "LIVE CLIENT SECRET",
});

router.post("/pay",isUserAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  const order_data = req.body.order_data;
  var create_payment_json = {
    intent: "sale",
    payer: {
      payment_method: "paypal",
    }, application_context: {
      brand_name:'BRAND NAME',
      shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
    },
    redirect_urls: {
      return_url:
        "https://rturn",
      cancel_url: "cancel",
    },
    transactions: [
      {
        item_list: {
          items: [
            {
              name: order_data.order_name,
              sku: order_data.order_name,
              price: order_data.price,
              currency: "USD",
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        amount: {
          currency: "USD",
          total: order_data.price,
        },
        application_context: {
          NOSHIPPING: 1,
        },
        description: order_data.order_details.msg,
      },
    ],
  };

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
        if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
          const OrderStart = new Order({
            order_owner: req.user._id,
            order_name: order_data.order_name,
            order_details: order_data.order_details,
            order_account: {
              email : Clean_input(order_data.Email) ,
              password : Clean_input(order_data.pwd) ,
            },
            order_statue: "waiting payment",
            order_price: {
              price: order_data.price,
              taxes: "0",
              total_price: order_data.price,
            },
            payment_methode: order_data.payment_method,
            payment_info: {
              payment_id: payment.id,
              payment_link: payment.links[i].href,
              payment_status: "waiting",
              payment_data: execute_payment_json,
            },
          });
          OrderStart.save(function (err, user) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (user) {
              console.log(user);
              res.status(201).json({ payment_link: payment.links[i].href });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

**FYI : In my code all credentials and redirects are well placed **

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED : I WAS USING WEBHOOKS.JS WITH SAME SANDBOX CONFIG THAT WAS THE PROBLEM**

Comment: Separately, it appears you're using the deprecated https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK .  Use the current https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK .

Comment: thank you sir <3